# Integrating HTML and PHP files

Tags: php, html, web

This is a very basic question, but after learning both html and php online, I am having trouble with writing simple code. I have two separate files test.html and test.php. I have them saved on my desktop. When I open test.html in my browser(chrome), it works but when I click 'submit' query, it only prints:

> Welcome:
>   your email address is:

What is it that I am doing wrong? Plus I want to ask how can I upload this on a web page?

This is the file: 'test.html'.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the file: 'test.php'

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a server running PHP to server PHP files. You can't just run them in the browser.

Comment: `when I click 'submit' query` - what (full) url does that take you to? Are you pointing at `C:\whatever\welcome.php`?

Comment: and your form action is wrong. there is no welcome.php file

Comment: You have set the form action as `welcome.php`. Set it to `test.php`, so the information is posted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP needs a web server in order to be parsed - it does not have native support like HTML does. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is an example of such a web server, that also includes support for MySQL-databases. You'd need to install such a webserver and place your files inside of the htdocs folder. Once having done so, access the files by actually going to your local adress in the browser, typically: `http://localhost/index.php` - or whatever you named your PHP/HTML file to.

**EDIT**

Commenter above also made a fair point. You set the form action to welcome.php, but you say this file is named test.php.